# Unable to boot Ubuntu 64-bit in Virtualbox on Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox, macbook-pro, hardware-virtualization, vt-x

I have latest generation Macbook Pro 7.1 (Intel Core 2 Duo) running Mac OS X 10.6.6. I installed Virtuabox 4.0.2 and tried to boot Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit iso. The boot options screen from the live CD came up:

[image]

However when I continued to load the live session, or installer for that matter, I encountered the following error:

[image]

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. 
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

I am not sure if VT-x is enabled or is supported in the Core 2 Duo of my Macbook Pro. But at least, I have both I/O APIC and VT-x enabled for hardware virtualization as told in the Virtualbox [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests).

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to MacTracker, you have a P8600 or P8800 CPU, and Intel says [it supports hardware virtualization](http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx).

Comment: Still unable to boot 64 bit Ubuntu :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

You should go back to your virtualbox "new machine wizard" (it's the thing that opens when you  hit "new") then when selecting your OS Type, select "Ubuntu" and switch the Version to "Ubuntu (64 bit)". This makes sure it enables the 64bit processor extensions for your machine.

Comment: Yep, that worked for me! It's a little odd that VirtualBox doesn't seem to make the CPU type selection a little more explicit/obvious. After all, someone might want to emulate running a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit machine.